# Windows server cannot start Apache tomcat due to port 443 is in use and cannot be killed

Tags: java, windows, apache, tomcat

Hi I cannot start apache tomcat 7.0.77 under my windows server 2012 due to this conflict,

```
netstat -a -n -o | findstr 443
  TCP    0.0.0.0:443            0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       4
  TCP    [::]:443               [::]:0                 LISTENING       4
```

which I cannot kill by kill the pid due to error:

```
Error: the proces with PID 4 could not be terminated
reason: access is denied.
```

I cannot change port in the server config file because another port is not being able to accessed in public. So my only choice is to terminate this conflict and use this port for tomcat.
I have tried to restart the server several times and looking for similar posts in this page.
I really don't know what caused this problem since tomcat used to work fine before. Only when I try to deploy new war file from tomcat gui manager then restart, start, stop apache tomcat service under service manager few times and it keep stopping right after I click start.
Any help please !!

Thank you !

Comment: yes, I have tried several times

Comment: looks like there is virus or server is hacked ? anyway, that should be able to detect which one is using 443 and kill it right ?

Comment: I am the administrator, what other right do I need ?

Comment: Have you checked whether Apache service is set to "Automatic" from service panel?

Comment: yes I did, tried both automatic, automatic (delayed start) and manual

Comment: So if you turn off the service and put it on manual, after reboot port 443 is already in use, even if Tomcat is down?  That means you have some other software accessing that port (like Apache or IIS?).  Find that, kill it, then your Tomcat will be ok.

Comment: after I kill some of them I lost remote desktop connection, not sure which one is using then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the solution by using process hacker at:
https://processhacker.sourceforge.io/
then go to processes kill that process using that port (note: you can lost remote desktop connection if that is the process related or your server could restart, but after a while all will be back, as for my case).